# Telegram Bot - PHP Webhook POST to file

Tags: php, webhooks, telegram-bot

I've already read the few questions about bot API, but can't find a solution.

My bot works fine without setting a webhook and processing /getUpdates. But I can't get it working setting "https://www.domain.com/page.php" as webhook.

I've got a shared hosting behind Cloudflare's Flexible SSL cert and browsers doesn't warn about it, so I assume it's working fine.

I'm trying to get Telegram's POST to a file to have a clue if webhook need diferent parsing, but it is empty and can't see ssl_acces.log, so I can't even watch if Telegram reach the page...

Here is the snippet:

```
$message = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
file_put_contents('telegram.txt', var_dump($message));
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

[SOLUTION]

The way to log is:

```
$debug = file_get_contents('php://input');
$fp = fopen('debug.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $debug);
fclose($fp);
```

And the solution is that the webhook must be set without wwww:
`/setwebhook?url=https://domain.com/page.php`

Comment: Also tried:

`$debug = file_get_contents('php://input');
$fp = fopen('debug.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $debug);
fclose($fp);`

Comment: `$message = json_decode($_POST, true);
file_put_contents('telegram.txt', $message);` why don't you try that way? Telegram webhook seems to be making a POST request.

Comment: Done @Ugur. Thanks but, no luck. I'm sending messages to my bot, but txt files are not showing... I think that Telegram is not reaching the page, but I don't know how to test it. If I try /getUpdates only says that is active:

`{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Error: Conflict: another webhook is active"}`

Comment: You can try to reach the page on your own and see if it is generating output. Also as the error message describes, web hook is not reaching your page at all.

Comment: @Ugur, did you tried it? Reading de API I think the message is saying that a webhook is set. If not, /getUpdates will show a json. Maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: I didn't try it. I guess you should check https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook and https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getupdates . If Telegram is not calling your script at all, first you need to deal with it. Then the we can discuss the problem in scope of programming.

Comment: @Ugur, reading the API I think the message says: "Hey, a webhook is active, nothing to see here at /getUpdates"... And yes, my question is why isn't Telegram reaching my webhook. Thanks.

Comment: In this case we need to check https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setwebhook what is the response of `setWebhook` request. Also there is note about self-signed certificates. `We currently do not support self-signed certificates.`  I don't think Cloudflare's SSL is self signed and invalid for Telegram. You can try to set another non-ssl url on and check if Telegram hitting that url. This way you can figure out if it's about ssl or Cloudflare at all. Also are you sure you are making the right move to trigger the web hook?

Comment: @Ugur, /setWebhook won't set a non https url: `{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Error: Bad webhook: Error: [webhook:[protocol:HTTP][host:www.domain.com][port:80][query:\/telegrambot.php]]:Error: HTTPS url must be provided for webhooks"}`

The only trigger to the webhook is sending messages to the Bot. I've tried asking Telegram CM at Twitter, but no answer...

Comment: According to the documentation, port 80 seems valid `Ports currently supported for Webhooks: 443, 80, 88, 8443.`  May documentation be deprecated? I guess Telegram people can answer this question best.

Comment: you're welcome. Telegram has interesting features. When you find a way I'd be glad to see the solution.

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar issue, and fixed it removing a line

```
 (RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ [OR])
```

from the `.htaccess` file

Comment: Thanks for de negative :applause: